# Fill area between parametric curve and x-axis

Tags: pgfplots

I have a feeling the answer is obvious, but I've had no success in finding an answer.

I have a parametric curve, and I would like to indicate an integral from *x*=1 to *x*=2. Here goes my MWE:

```
\documentclass [border = 5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            axis lines = middle,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            xmin = -1, xmax = 3,
            ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
            grid = both,
            ]
            \addplot [domain = 0:1.2, samples = 50] ({3 * \x * \x - \x}, {sin (\x / pi * 180});
            \clip plot [domain = 0:1.2, samples = 50] ({3 * \x * \x - \x}, {sin (\x / pi * 180});
            \draw [fill = blue!20] (axis cs:1, 0) rectangle (axis cs:2, 1);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I had the simplistic idea of clipping to the curve, then drawing a rectangle, but this does not work (and I think demonstrates I have a lot more work to do in improving my understanding of PGFPlots!)

Any help on getting the required area filled in would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX StackExchange!

Your idea was close! Instead of using `\clip plot`, PGFPlots has a library called `fill between` which is your friend in this situation. You can use it to fill a color between any two plots, and it has its own clipping option, `soft clip`, which lets you restrict the domain of the filling.

[image: A curve moves from the origin into quadrant II, then into quadrant I. A region of integration between x = 1 and x = 2 is filled with blue.]

```
\documentclass [border = 5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            axis lines = middle,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            xmin = -1, xmax = 3,
            ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
            grid = both,
        ]
        \addplot[name path = curve,domain = 0:1.2, samples = 50] ({3 * \x^2 - \x}, {sin (\x / pi * 180});
        \path[name path = horizontalAxis] (axis cs: 3,0) -- (axis cs:-1,0);
        \addplot[fill = blue!20] fill between [of=horizontalAxis and curve,soft clip = {domain=1:2}];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For your own future reference, it's worth noting that I tailored the code below to fit your specific parametric equation. The `fill between` library attempts to connect the first and last points of each of the named paths, but this means that the horizontal axis path needs to be oriented from high to low (3 to −1) in order to work. Furthermore, with the way your curve is parameterized, this code only works for a strictly positive domain. (If you're curious, try out what happens when you set lower bound of the `soft clip` domain to zero versus anything *slightly* above zero.) As a result, if you're planning on making other plots by reusing this same code, you may encounter strange behavior.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! I will have to explore/play with the `fill between` library more :-)